# GNOME extension to make top-bar items have their own status menus?

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, top-bar

Is there a GNOME extension which would make all of the top-bar items have their own separate pull-down menus rather than being group into 2 or 3 big menus?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 with GNOME 3.24.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNOME Shell extension [Extend Panel Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/) does just that!
Follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/757326/364819) in order to install it.

Once you've installed it you will see that all your top-bar status items have their own dedicated menus:

[image: Example of one of the separate status menus]

And if you go to the menu which has your username on it (the one which says `Unknown` on mine) you can access the `Extension Settings`:

[image: Extension settings]

Comment: +2, one for Q and one for A. We'll all need to know this eventually when Unity is dropped and we switch over to Gnome DE in Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you for bravely going where no Panda has gone before.

Comment: I'm glad that both of you liked the extension and found it useful. :)